# Prolog looking for the inorder location of an element in tree(without using lists)

Tags: prolog

I am trying to go through a binary tree in an inorder traveling method
my target is to find the occurance of a specific key in the tree
for example,
i have the following tree:

```
t(t(t(nil,"d",t(nil,"g",nil)),"b",t(nil,"e",nil)),"a",t(t(nil,"f",t(nil,"h",nil)),"c",nil))
```

when i will use my inorder_finder i will get the following:
for "c" i will get 8
for  "d" i will get 1
for "w" i will get -1

I have come up to the following code:

```
inorder_finder(nil,_,_,0).

inorder_place(t(_,X,_),X,Count,Place) :-
    Place is Count+1.

inorder_place(t(L,_,R),Wanted,Count,Place) :-
        inorder_place(L,Wanted,Count+1,Place),
        Place<1, 
        inorder_place(R,Wanted,Count+1,Place),
        Place<1,
        Count = Count+1.
```

and i call the following predicate:

```
inorder_finder inorder_place(t(t(t(nil,"d",t(nil,"g",nil)),"b",t(nil,"e",nil)),"a",t(t(nil,"f",t(nil,"h",nil)),"c",nil)),"c",1,Place)
```

but it doesnt work at the moment. (just always returns false)
any ideas?

update: I have updated the code according to the comments i got - it still returns false and doesnt work as i would like it to

Comment: _"c" i will get 8_ why?? your tree does not have `"c"` at all?

Comment: This is a little confusing. Do place positions start at 1 or 0? Your invalid place is set to -1, but your code continues searching if place is < 1, implying that 0 is considered an invalid place indicator. And what do you mean *it doesn't work at the moment?* In what way does it not work? Finally, if you call the predicate as you show `inorder_finder ( ...` you'll get an error since, In Prolog, you cannot have a space between functor and left parenthesis.

Comment: HI - first thanks I have updated the tree(it didnt copy the second line i wrote with c) and updated the predicate to be without the space, I need its first indicator to be 1, any suggestion what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Place = Count + 1 should be Place **is** Count + 1

Comment: A couple of things wrong on inspection... If the correct first indicator is 1 as you say, then I'd suggest `inorder_finder (nil,_,_,0).` instead of `inorder_finder (nil,_,_,Place) :-
    Place = -1.`. The reason being  your predicate depends upon the increment of count, so with -1 your base case it would result in an invalid 0 count at some point due to increment. Also, note that `Count is Count + 1` will ALWAYS fail since `Count` can never have the same value as `Count + 1`. `inorder_finder(t(L,_,R),Wanted,Count,Place)` will always fail since it has no complete success path.

Comment: Thanks for all of your help - I have updated the code according to the comments - it still returns false and doesnt work as i would like it to

Comment: You have not addressed all of the issues already mentioned. Please read them again carefully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most obvious errors have been mentioned in comments, what still remain are:

1. `Place<1` : I don't get why?? Place may has value greater than 1.
2. `inorder_place`: never defined...
3. `inorder_place(t(_,X,_),X,Count,Place):-Place is Count+1.`: even if you find the letter you need first recursively enumerate the left branch of tree and then Place of wanted letter (see answer below)
4. I think the problem could be solved in two parts, one in-order-enumerate all nodes then simply traverse until you find the right node. Though I didn't followed this version (even it is more clear) since with a simple-mixed solution it is more efficient since you may not need to enumerate all nodes. For this attempt that you're trying to do **I think you need two counters** **- first one** the counter when calling inorder_find(..) e.g when entering, **second counter** will return where the counting stopped in order to continue from there in the right branch of tree.
5. `inorder_finder inorder_place(...)`:still not valid syntax for calling the predicate- it should return error not false...

My implementation:

```
inorder_finder(nil,_,Count,Count,-1).

inorder_finder(t(L,X,_),X,Count,Count2,Place):-
                inorder_finder(L,X,Count,Count3,_),
                Place is Count3+1,Count2 is Place.

inorder_finder(t(L,X,R),Wanted,Count,Count2,Place):-
                dif(X,Wanted),
                inorder_finder(L,Wanted,Count,Count3,Place1),
                Count4 is Count3+1,
                inorder_finder(R,Wanted,Count4,Count2,Place2),
                Place is max(Place1,Place2).
```

Examples:

```
?- inorder_finder(t(t(t(nil,"d",t(nil,"g",nil)),"b",t(nil,"e",nil)),"a",t(t(nil,"f",t(nil,"h",nil)),"c",nil)),"c",0,_,P).
P = 8 ;
false.

?- inorder_finder(t(t(t(nil,"d",t(nil,"g",nil)),"b",t(nil,"e",nil)),"a",t(t(nil,"f",t(nil,"h",nil)),"c",nil)),"W",0,_,P).
P = -1.

?- inorder_finder(t(t(t(nil,"d",t(nil,"g",nil)),"b",t(nil,"e",nil)),"a",t(t(nil,"f",t(nil,"h",nil)),"c",nil)),"d",0,_,P).
P = 1 ;
false.
```